# Shopify - Edit or replace an image asset

Tags: shopify

I have an image in my theme that displays icons on the website. Its a sprite image. I want to edit this image. I went to Edit Theme > Theme Actions > Edit Code > Assets > image.jpg. I can see it but I don't have any option to edit or replace it. Is this possible to do?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello, you should be able to upload another image.

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Comment: After you press on customize theme you should see where to upload the new image. [Reference](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/os/using-themes/change-the-layout/images#upload-images)

Comment: simply delete it and upload the new one, and use it into CSS